# How can I enable pid and ppid fields in psacct dump-acct?

Tags: pid, accounting

I am currently using the psacct package on Centos to perform accounting on processes run by users.

The info file[1](http://www.gnu.org/software/acct/manual/html_chapter/accounting_7.html#SEC24) suggests that it is possible to output pid and ppid depending on what information your operating system provides in it's struct acct.

pid and ppid are listed in /usr/include/linux/acct.h on my system:

```
struct acct_v3
{
        char            ac_flag;                /* Flags */
        char            ac_version;             /* Always set to ACCT_VERSION */
        __u16           ac_tty;                 /* Control Terminal */
        __u32           ac_exitcode;            /* Exitcode */
        __u32           ac_uid;                 /* Real User ID */
        __u32           ac_gid;                 /* Real Group ID */
        __u32           ac_pid;                 /* Process ID */
        __u32           ac_ppid;                /* Parent Process ID */
...
```

But pid and ppid are not output when I run dump-acct:

```
# dump-acct /var/account/pacct.1 | tail
awk              |   0.0|   0.0|  81.0|    0|    0|8792.0|Thu Nov 24 04:03:04 2011
tmpwatch         |   0.0|   0.0|   1.0|    0|    0|3816.0|Thu Nov 24 04:03:04 2011
cups             |   0.0|   0.0|   4.0|    0|    0|8728.0|Thu Nov 24 04:03:04 2011
awk              |   0.0|   0.0|   4.0|    0|    0|8792.0|Thu Nov 24 04:03:04 2011
runlevel         |   0.0|   0.0|   0.0|    0|    0|3804.0|Thu Nov 24 04:03:04 2011
chkconfig        |   0.0|   0.0|   0.0|    0|    0|3840.0|Thu Nov 24 04:03:04 2011
inn-cron-expire  |   0.0|   0.0|   0.0|    0|    0|8728.0|Thu Nov 24 04:03:04 2011
awk              |   0.0|   0.0|   0.0|    0|    0|8792.0|Thu Nov 24 04:03:04 2011
gzip             |   5.0|   0.0|   9.0|    0|    0|4044.0|Thu Nov 24 04:03:04 2011
accton           |   0.0|   0.0|   1.0|    0|    0|   0.0|Thu Nov 24 04:03:04 2011
```

Is it likely that there is no support in my kernel for this feature or that my psacct version does not support this?

How can I add pid and ppid to my accounting logs?

CentOS release 5.6

Kernel 2.6.18-238.19.1.el5

psacct 6.3.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found this in the [changelog for the psacct RPM](http://pkgs.org/centos-6-rhel-6/centos-rhel-i386/psacct-6.3.2-63.el6.i686.rpm.html):

```
* Fri Nov 13 2009 Ivana Varekova <varekova(at)redhat.com> - 6.3.2-56
  - fix the psacct to deal with all acct types and
    if it is possible and wanted then add the possibility
    to display the pid and ppid number
```

So it looks like it depends in exactly which release you are using.

Answer (score 2):

```
CentOS release 5.6
psacct 6.3.2
```

The `psacct` package shipped with CentOS 5.6 has release number 44:

```
Name       : psacct
Arch       : x86_64
Version    : 6.3.2
Release    : 44.el5
Size       : 107 k
Repo       : installed
Summary    : Utilities for monitoring process activities.
License    : GPL
Description: The psacct package contains several utilities for monitoring process
           : activities, including ac, lastcomm, accton and sa. The ac command
           : displays statistics about how long users have been logged on. The
           : lastcomm command displays information about previous executed
           : commands. The accton command turns process accounting on or off. The
           : sa command summarizes information about previously executed
           : commands.
```

and as @Ladadadada mentioned, according to the change log, PID and PPID are only available from 6.3.2-56 version. On my CentOS 6 (psacct-6.3.2-63):

```
accton           |   0.0|   0.0|   1.0|    0|    0|3832.0|   16114    16111|Thu Nov 24 13:37:50 2011
touch            |   0.0|   0.0|   3.0|    0|    0|105088.0|   16115    16111|Thu Nov 24 13:37:50 2011
psacct           |   0.0|   0.0|   9.0|    0|    0|106304.0|   16111    16059|Thu Nov 24 13:37:50 2011
w                |   0.0|   0.0|   3.0|    0|    0|105280.0|   16116    16059|Thu Nov 24 13:37:52 2011
```